# How to interact with google tab: Who's using chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

in my code I open chrome and the tab that opens first is the next: see picture.[Google's who's using chrome tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDmdy.png)

I would like to interact with it to use either of the profiles( which I prefer at the time )
I tried pyautogui, ActionChains and Controller from pynput.keyboard to send keys( tab ) but it doesn't react for any of these.

I don't link code as I guess it doesn't have any sense because whatever I want to open with google it asks me this.

Note: I know I am able to skip this tab, but that's not my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that time the only solution I came up with is to precisely write code to move the cursor and click on the adequate 'button'.